# 64 bit build issue. Confusing/ incorrect error message

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image]I have a visual studio 2019 project that requires a 64 bit build due to dependence on some nuget packages.

As you can see, I have changed the build targets to 64-bit but it doesn't seem to be able to move past the same complaint.

What am I missing here? Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2019 or am I doing something wrong?

Changed all built targets to 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

While you're looking at the specific build options for a Configuration called "All Configurations", where the Platform is set to "X64". But note your settings in your IDE's toolbar. You're currently targeting/building the "Debug" Configuration for "Any CPU".

To better understand what's going on here, right click on your Solution node in the Solution Explorer and select the "Configuration Manager..." menu item.

Given you require X64, you can/should remove the configurations that allow you to target x86 or ANY CPU. I suspect you are just building the wrong configuration here. That "All Configurations", is probably being brought along by one or more C++ projects in your solution.

Sincerely,